# Problema com cores hexadecimais de 8 dígitos - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Estou trabalhando em um aplicativo onde estou tentando seguir o guia de design Material do Google. Nessa página, recomenda-se usar a cor preta (`#000000`) com 87% de opacidade como a cor dos textos principais.

Utilizando um conversor de decimal para hexadecimal, cheguei ao valor de 57 na base hex. Unindo a opacidade desejada com a cor, cheguei que a cor final deveria ser `#57000000`, porém o resultado foi esse:

[image: Cor dos textos muito clara]

Enquanto deveria se parecer com isso:

[image: Cor do texto material]

Minha pergunta é: houve erro de cálculo por minha parte? Não é assim que deve ser calculada a opacidade? O valor da opacidade varia de 0-100 ou de 0-255?

O meu arquivo xml de cores é esse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- cores do android L -->
    <color name="texto">#57000000</color>
    <color name="texto_secundario">#36000000</color>
    <color name="dica">#1A000000</color>
    <color name="divisores">#0C000000</color>

    <color name="laranja">#ffab40</color>
    <color name="laranja_escuro">#ff9100</color>
    <color name="laranja_claro">#ffd180</color>

    <color name="roxo">#673ab7</color>
    <color name="roxo_escuro">#512da8</color>
    <color name="roxo_claro">#d1c4e9</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tanto as cores quanto as opacidades no "formato web" costumam ser interpretadas de `00` a `ff`, ou seja, de 0 a 255 em decimal.

Multiplicando 0xFF (255) por 0,87 dá um valor próximo a 0xDD (221), portanto o preto na transparência desejada seria:

```
   #dd000000
```

Segue uma tabela básica como referência:

```
     0% 0x00          0 
     5% 0x0D         13 
    10% 0x1A         26 
    15% 0x26         38 
    20% 0x33         51 
    25% 0x40         64 
    30% 0x4D         77 
    35% 0x59         89 
    40% 0x66        102 
    45% 0x73        115 
    50% 0x80        128 
    55% 0x8C        140 
    60% 0x99        153 
    65% 0xA6        166 
    70% 0xB3        179 
    75% 0xBF        191 
    80% 0xCC        204 
    85% 0xD9        217 
    90% 0xE6        230 
    95% 0xF2        242 
   100% 0xFF        255
```

E aqui, os valores desejados no enunciado:

```
    12% 0x1e         30
    26% 0x42         66
    54% 0x89        137 
    87% 0xDD        221
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta rápida! Pelo visto foi apenas um erro de cálculo meu. Não pensei na possibilidade de o intervalo ser de 255 valores, ao invés de 100 como havia considerado.

Comment: @RenanLazarotto acrescentei a tabela dos valores de transparência que você mencionou no enunciado.

Comment: Novamente, obrigado! Vou salvar essa lista para referência futura.